# Merging two video streams in one stream like Picture in Picture (WMF)

Tags: windows, video, directx-11, ms-media-foundation

I am learning Windows Media Foundation.
I have tested few of the sample application provided in the Windows SDK.
I have sample application for Video capture from camera and video playback from file.

What I want to archive is to combine both of these video sources in one video source and then generate one video stream like Picture in Picture. How this can be done in Windows media foundation?

I have reading about `MFCreateAggregateSource`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388085(v=vs.85).aspx

Can `MFCreateAggregateSource` be used in this case, or it is used just for mixing audio and video stream?

I want to place one video in full screen mode and then display another video stream on top of it, on top right corner of the first video in a small window.

How this can be done using media foundation?

** Update **

I am more concern about, reading two video stream using WMF decoding them and then mixing them and then re-encoding them and then writing to a file. And not rendering them on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFCreateAggregateSource will not do the video mixing. It will just create one source from two sources that could be used by a MediaSession (through Topology and TopologyNode) for example.

If you just want to display the two videos, you can use [Enhanced Video Renderer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms694916(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can use MFCreateAggregateSource and connect each streams to EVR. If you don't want to handle timestamping/decoder/etc..., you will have also to use a media session (IMFMediaSesion).

Comment: This is what exactly I did, but now I am struggling with displaying two video separately in one window. I have tried to use `m_pVideoMixerControl->SetStreamOutputRect(0, &rect)` but it is not working. How it can be done.

Comment: What values do you pass. rect is in the range 0.0 to 1.0. For example MFVideoNormalizedRect rcHalf = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5 }; Also check Identifier of the stream is correct with m_pStreamSink->GetIdentifier.

Answer (score 1):

Your task is very unusual and THERE IS NOT ANY Media Foundation component which allows merge two video streams into the one. However, 'IMFMediaSesion' supports working with two video stream in one source via 'MFCreateAggregateSource'. It means that Media Foundation like 'LEGO' contractor which allows you WRITE YOUR OWN SOLUTION WHICH merge two video streams into the one like Picture in Picture, but it does not support such functionality by itself.

Regards.

P.S. I would like advise read book 'Developing Microsoft® Media Foundation Applications'
Book by 'Anton Polinger' ([Developing Microsoft® Media Foundation Applications](http://dl.finebook.ir/book/9a/10863.pdf)) - it includes many examples for one stream, but it includes code for 'WaterMarkTransform' - code Media Foundation Transform for injection of image into the video stream - such code cam be started for your solution - inject one video stream into the another one.

P.S. I have got a mistake - I see that you want ONLY DISPLAY Picture in Picture - so EVR - default video renderer supports 16 video streams - one reference and 15 additional - you need create 'VideoRenderer' via 'MFCreateVideoRendererActivate' and then create for each of video streams (in your case for each of two stream) `TopologyNode`, set for each `TopologyNode` already created 'VideoRenderer' by set 'SetObject' - as a result many video streams will use ONE 'VideoRenderer'. BY setting `SetUINT32` for `TopologyNode` with 'MF_TOPONODE_STREAMID' you must select which stream will be reference - 'background Picture' - by setting 0, and which stream will be `additional Picture` with 'MF_TOPONODE_STREAMID' more than 0 (for example 1). 
Position of `additional Picture` can be controlled by [IMFVideoMixerControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms700190(v=vs.85).aspx) - it includes the next methods: 
GetStreamOutputRect - Retrieves the position of a video stream within the composition rectangle.

GetStreamZOrder - Retrieves the z-order of a video stream.

SetStreamOutputRect - Sets the position of a video stream within the composition rectangle.

SetStreamZOrder - Sets the z-order of a video stream.

Comment: Hi @Evgeny Pereguda: Thanks for posting this detail answer it is very helpful. So as per the last update it is possible to mix two video stream using windows media foundation. In case if you have any example of implementing this or any document that can describe how exactly it is implemented that will help me in understanding the flow. Also I am bit confused with topology how exactly it is used while implementation. Again thanks for helping.

Comment: Hi @Evgeny Pereguda: Also in case if we want to save the mixed video (Picture in Picture) to a file then how that can done?

Comment: I can recommend to read  'Developing Microsoft® Media Foundation Applications' Book by 'Anton Polinger' - it one book which explain conception of Media Foundation Topology. I have code examples for that book - .Also, you can research my project om Media Foundation [Capturing Live-video from Web-camera on Windows 7 and Windows 8](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/776058/capturing-live-video-from-web-camera-on-windows-an) - this project has code for working with web camera - it includes example with injection image into the live video - 'WaterMark'.

Comment: About 'to save the mixed video (Picture in Picture) to a file' - it is very unusual solution, and I do not have code for it. However, media session can work with IMFTransform object with more than one input video streams - I think that it is possible write code like 'WaterMark' which can inject image from one file into the image of the another one. The fact is that it needs get two image in input, write code for mixing and send result in output.

Answer (score 1):

MFCreateAggregateSource or even the Sequencer Source might work ok for video mixing, but in order to have more control over the process, in a project I'm involved in, I used multiple MFSourceReaders to MFSinkWriter approach. This way I can both display the mixed video contents if I attach EVR to the sink writer, or store the output video in a file. In the project I'm working on, the requirement is only to output to mp4, but later I'll have to add a preview support. For this purpose, I plan to use two sink writers - one for EVR (or DX11VideoRenderer) and one for MP4 sink. The implementation works very stable. It has a video mixing thread that reads from each source reader, matches the timestamps, mixes video samples and outputs the mixed video sample or the audio sample (only one) to the sink writer.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Will it be possible to provide more details on this Or any example of components that are involved in mixing two video streams. Currently I am not worried about displaying mixed streams but, 1. Reading two streams, 2. Mixing them and then writing to a file. So I will read streams decode them using WMF API, then Mix them then re-encode them and then write to a file.

Comment: The idea is to create an IMFSourceReader for each source (file, capture). Implement an IMFSourceReaderCallback for each one of them in order to receive the samples asynchronously and put each sample in a queue. Then in a separate thread dequeue the samples and mix the video samples (using directx for instance). You can configure the IMFSourceReaders with DirectX manager taken from an EVR or created by you (a DX device). You can feed the mixed video samples to an EVR via an IMFSinkWriter object. Or you can check the MFCaptureD3D sample, to see how to draw the mixed samples directly using DX.

Comment: Thanks for the details. How can we use DirectX for mixing two stream samples? Also how can we configure EVR for display when we have mixed samples.

Comment: You can use the DirectX device created by you, or taken from EVR's device manager. You can query DX11 Video Processor device and use VideoProcessorBlt to make the mixing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447677(v=vs.85).aspx. This will work on Windows 8 and higher. For earlier versions you can use DXVA-HD or DXVA2.

Comment: With EVR you have also the option to try to use AddStream for the Sink Writer to add second video input to EVR.

Comment: Here is some sample code. It uses only the first input of EVR. But you should be able to figure out how to enable and configure the second: https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/blob/master/MFVideoEVR/MFVideoEVR.cpp

Comment: Thanks for the details: I am able to create two stream using stream aggregator. And Using EVR I am trying render them.  I am able to hear sounds of two videos but I am able to see video of only first video stream. How I can position two video stream in one renderer? I have tried using m_pVideoMixerControl->SetStreamOutputRect(0, &objRect); but it is not working.

Comment: You need to use AddStream twice on the Sink Writer in order to use EVR with it. This way you'll create two input streams on the Sink Writer (which will be mapped to EVR's inputs). And then use ProcessSample on each Sink Writer input separately for each video input. This approach may not work with IMFMediaSink though.